# Django: How to iterate List containing Dicts

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I get Json data and then convert it to python object.
Here is the code:

```
    number = request.POST.get('num')
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:9000/findexclusive"
    querystring = {"num":number}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, params=querystring)
    response = response.json()
    response = json.loads(response)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'details':response})
```

Now I get a valid response. But not able to convert this data in to html page.
Data I get is like below:

```
[{u'pk': 1233, u'model': u'details.modelname', u'fields': {a': u'xyz', u'b': u'something', u'c': u'something', u'd': u''}}]
```

How do I iterate this.

These are not working:

```
for data in b[0]:
...     for key,value in data.items:
...         print key
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'
>>> a = data.json()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `response[0]` you already get dict item. So `for data in response[0]` will give you list of dict's key. You can just use:

```
for data in response:
     for key,value in data.items:
         print key
```

Also note you can remove this line `response = json.loads(response)`. Since `response = response.json()` already give you decoded JSON.